# Login with twitter in ios7 and fetching twitter user profile

Tags: twitter, ios7

I want to integrate twitter in ios 7 and want to achieve following features.
1. Login with twitter from iOS app.
2. Fetch user profile information

I have tried couple of solution but none of them is working for me. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having same issue but I came across following open source framework and solved my problem.

https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/

Interacting with twitter through this framework is very easy.

**Steps to solve your problem;**

Setup STTwitter framework as given in following link
http://tutorials.veasoftware.com/2013/12/23/twitter-api-version-1-1-app-authentication/

1.First you verify twitter credentials.
2.Fetch twitter user information and then parse.

I am using following function

```
- (IBAction)loginWithTwitter:(id)sender {
    self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];
    [_twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock: ^(NSString *username) {
        [_twitter getUserInformationFor:username successBlock: ^(NSDictionary *user) {
            NSLog(@"user profile %@", user);
        }

                             errorBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                             }];
    } errorBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error message %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}
```

I hope it helps.